# Oracle: how do I compare two set of data?

Tags: sql, oracle

The question has been answered here: [Oracle: I need a "partial" outer join. Look at the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421316/oracle-i-need-a-partial-outer-join-look-at-the-image#comment11910418_9421316)

Look at the table. I've done a join the column CodA is from table A, the CodB is from table B.
If I have the following situation my comparison goes wrong.

I would like to see a result like in the 3rd image. Should I do it using a Full outer JOIN?

```
SELECT master, detail, codA, codB, DECODE(A, B, 'Equal', 'Not equal')
FROM A, B
WHERE a.master = b.master
AND a.detail = b.detail
```

**I also need to make a full outer Join JUST for the a.CodA = b.CodB statement, but not for the a.master = b.master statement. It must use normal JOIN there.**

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: What would you want to happen if B had a row with master and detail the same and codB = 5?

Comment: In the query result (third image), how can 2 be in `CodB` if it does not exist in the table (second image)? Also, what is the fourth image?

Comment: I would like to see master, detail, null, codB = 5. I try to explain in another way. The full outer join just takes all record matching and not. I want to take JUST matching records for the a.master = b.master statement and ALL the records if they differ JUST for the codA/B column. I want to compare the difference like in that excel in the image.

Comment: Just consider the records having 1-C3LFJX as master value, table A and B are extrapoleted just from that code.

Answer (score 1):

A full outer join would also display the elements that exist in B and not in A

For instance, if you had a codB=5, in your last image you will also have a record with CodA=NULL and CodB=5. Another option is to left join tables A and B. The same example I've just provided would result in the same image you provided with a left join.

In conclusion if you want to ALSO display in your result elements from B that do not match with elements from A, go for a full outer join. If you want to display all elements from A and their matches (or not) with elements from B go for A left join B.

PS: Currently you are doing an inner join, that means you are matching elments in A that have a correspondant element in B

Comment: Yes, but I currently don't use the WHERE clause on CodA = CodB. So it acts like a small cartesian join.