# Oracle: I need a "partial" outer join. Look at the image

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope it's clear. How can I achieve the result showed in the following image?

[image]

Comment: What you've shown as a "natural join" isn't by my understanding of the term, unless `ColA` and `ColB` actually have the same name and therefore are join columns.

Comment: Yes, sorry, take "ColA" and "ColB" as an alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do an outer join but also use coalesce

```
SELECT
   COALESCE(a.master,b.master) master,
   a.ColA,
   b.ColB
FROM
  a FULL OUTER JOIN B
  ON a.master = b.master
     AND (a.ColA = b.ColB 
          or a.ColA is Null
          or b.ColB is Null)
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(a.master,b.master),
    COALESCE(a.cola,b.colB)
```

See it working [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62380/sample-for-9421316)

Comment: I think he also wants an equality on `ColA` and `ColB` to be part of the join conditions.

Comment: @Dave Costa I totally missed that. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I also discovered COALESCE operator.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce

Comment: There is another thing I don't understand. If I want to filter on a single value I have to put all in in a view and filter after that. I can't simply filter as follows you can see here:
http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62426/filtering-on-coalescent-outer-join

Comment: @Gik25 -- you've put the filter condition in the join conditions portion of the query.  Since it's an outer join, the join conditions don't act as filters.  You should use a separate WHERE clause for your filter conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  masters.master AS master,
  TableA.ColA AS ColA,
  TableB.ColB AS ColB,
FROM
    (
      SELECT master FROM TableA
      UNION
      SELECT master FROM TableB
    ) AS masters
    LEFT JOIN TableA ON masters.master=TableA.master
    LEFT JOIN TableB ON masters.master=TableB.master
ORDER BY
    master, ColA, ColB
```

Comment: this is a good answer for MySQL (since it doesn't support full outer join) but this isn't required for Oracle.

Comment: IMHO this is a portable answer, that should (after optimization) result in a query plan very close to that of a full outer join

Comment: The problem of course is that if join conditions get more complicated this gets nasty. This is actually the case here as (like I did) you missed the requirement that Dave Costa pointed out. Compare the output from [your query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62381/sample-for-post-9421369) and the OP's desired results.